# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

На строке

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime
>   error occurred. Во время запуска экземпляра LocalDB произошла ошибка:
>   ошибка запуска процесса SQL Server. )

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public ApplicationDbContext() : base()
        {
        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        }

        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
```

.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly ISmsSender _smsSender;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly string _externalCookieScheme;

        public AccountController(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IOptions<IdentityCookieOptions> identityCookieOptions,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            ISmsSender smsSender,
            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _externalCookieScheme = identityCookieOptions.Value.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _smsSender = smsSender;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountController>();
        }
```

.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet-WebApplicationCore-42a4ac05-477c-4ea7-b286-87423170b48a;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А как пытались исправить проблему? Решений в гугле по этому вопросу предостаточно

Comment: при этом каждый раз пользователь создаётся нормально. Пользователи появляются в бд. После этого происходит ошибка. И var result  возвращает null

Comment: добавьте тело метода `_userManager.CreateAsync()` к вопросу

Comment: стандартный приложения aspnet core

Comment: вы используете `LocalDb`? Попробуйте сменить коннекшн стрингу ради проверки

Comment: на какой изменить? да, в вопрос добавлена строка

Comment: у вас есть `SQL Management Studio`? Там создайте базу на локале и скопируйте стрингу в конфиг

Comment: нету...........

Comment: `Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplicationCore-42a4ac05-477c-4ea7-b286-87423170b48a;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False`

Comment: тогда `InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.`